# How to get all Nodes from Cytoscape

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

How do I get all IDs from Nodes in my Cytoscape Canvas?
For context: I need them for Frontendtesting via Selenium

Comment: ` cy.json().elements.nodes[index].data.id `

Comment: `cy.nodes().map(x => x.id())`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.